# The prefix "http" for element "http:conduit" is not bound - what does this mean?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, cxf, applicationcontext

I am trying to [configure SSL](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-ConfiguringSSLSupport) support for my CXF-based client per [this official Apache CXF guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-ConfiguringSSLSupport), but Eclipse marks the `http:conduit` tag with a red underline and very short error description:

```
  The prefix "http" for element "http:conduit" is not bound
```

I searched the web for additional clues regarding the meaning of this message and how to fix it but I have not found yet anything that could explain why I am getting this error.

Any idea what *The prefix "http" for element "http:conduit" is not bound* means?

Bound to what?

Why only the prefix "http" and not "conduit"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `http` in `http:conduit` is the namespace that the `conduit` element belongs to.

Look at the example in the link you posted. You need to specify the namespace and schema location for the elements you use.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
  xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, when I added `xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"` the red underline moved to `<sec:keyManagers` (but still having the red **X** next to the http conduit), then I added `xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"` and the red underline under `<sec:keyManagers` disappeared but the red **X** next to the http conduit, still complaining about *The prefix "http" for element "http:conduit" is not bound*.  Why is this happening and how I can get rid of this once and for all?

Comment: Weird. The problem seems to have disappeared. Must have been unstable Eclipse with the whimsical maven plugins. Accepting now.

Comment: @sfinja Sometimes Eclipse fails to synchronize your changes. Typically, you just need to clean/rebuild.